# Can a custom directive set the placeholder for an input using Angular Material?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, directive, placeholder

Consider my html:

```html
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput myCustomDirective
      formControlName="email"
    >
  </md-input-container>
```

In my custom directive, I want to set the placeholder.

I tried naive code like this and failed:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[myCustomDirective]',
})
export class MyCustomDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer2: Renderer2,
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer2.setAttribute(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      'placeholder',
      'test',
    );
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I put the setAttribute code in the constructor or in any of the lifecycle hooks.

Is there another way I haven't thought of?

I'm using reactive forms and OnPush change detection strategy if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you try this instead of all the elementRef/renderer stuff? `@HostBinding('attr.placeholder') placeholder = 'test';`

Comment: normally, i think that would work. And indeed it sets the placeholder attribute of the input element to 'test'. But that's not good enough for angular material to actually display the placeholder. I need to figure out how to make angular material aware of the placeholder and to use it. I was hoping there was some bit of angular material api to support this, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, although it's pretty hacky (because MdInputDirective's placeholder field is actually an input). Although, any imperative-style solution tastes bad to me.

```
import {MdInputDirective} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myCustomDirective]'
})
export class MyCustomDirective {
  constructor(@Self() private input: MdInputDirective) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.input.placeholder = 'test';
  }
}
```

An alternate solution could be something like: Put your directive on the md-input-container element instead of the input element, then create a myCustomDirectivePlaceholder component, which injects myCustomDirective to get the needed string, and use them like so:

```
<md-input-container myCustomDirective>
  <input mdInput>
  <md-placeholder>
    <myCustomDirectivePlaceholder></myCustomDirectivePlaceholder>
  </md-placeholder>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Perfect! I forgot about @Self, neat trick. Your first option was exactly what I was looking for. I should have mentioned that one of the purposes of my directive is to reduce the amount of html boilerplate necessary in the template.

Comment: Actually, I think it'll work without Self, but using Self limits the dependency injection to only things on the same element, so it's "safer" (and kinda self-documenting too). 'Host' is like that too.

Comment: Yes, confirmed works without @Self, so I guess the trick here is that directives can be injected like this. Very cool, I learned something. Thanks.